# Mensaje de spam en aplicación de React Native

Tags: react-native, popup

Cordial saludo, desarrollando una aplicación en React Native para la empresa dónde actualmente trabajo, me empezó a aparecer un mensaje de spam bastante extraño, he revisado el código fuente pero en ningún lado veo que se esté generando ese popup. Necesito realizar un despliegue a producción pero no puedo hacerlo con ese popup que aparece y desaparece. Sospecho que puede ser por alguno de los paquetes de node que tengo instalados, tal vez al realizar alguna actualizaciones de los paquetes. A continuación adjunto una imagen del popup que me aparece, si tienen alguna idea de cómo eliminar esto se los agradecería.

Pdta: Al buscar por el texto que aparece en el popup no se encuentran resultados y tampoco puedo inspeccionar el elemento con las herramientas de desarrollo ya que no se deja seleccionar.

[mensaje de spam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Xwl.png)

Deseo eliminar ese popup para poder realizar un despliegue a producción.